# Google-like plotting symbol?

Tags: google-maps, icons, symbols

I'm looking for some additional plot symbols. Here's my code as it stands:

```
library(maps)
map('state', 'north carolina')
x <- c(-81.18668,-78.38062)
y <- c(35.7767,35.7767)
points(x=x, y=y)
```

What I'm looking for are plot symbols similar to those used on Google Maps, preferably those used in directions maps (ie, point A and point B).

Are there any packages out there with these symbols built in, or does anyone have an idea for a quick hack? Thanks!

EDIT: Looking for plotting symbols like those showing the two points here:

http://goo.gl/maps/xjxqn

Basically, tear-drop shaped with labels (A and B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is kind of vague,
but here are some icons:
http://www.bestpsdfreebies.com/freebie/map-marker-icons/

Another library: http://abeliantechnologies.com/google_map_marker.php

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but my fault. I added some more info.

Comment: http://www.bestpsdfreebies.com/freebie/google-maps-ui-kit-freebie/ <- Tear-drop. If that doesn't suit you, you'll have to be more specific. Do you want PNG or just PSD-files?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using the `my.symbols` function in the TeachingDemos package:

```
library(TeachingDemos)
ms.mappoint <- function(letter='', col='blue', txtcol='white', cex=1, ...) {
    tmp <- seq( -3*pi/8, 11*pi/8, length.out=200 )
    tmp.x <- cos(tmp)/3
    tmp.y <- sin(tmp)/3 + 2/3

    tmp.x <- c(tmp.x, 0, tmp.x[1])
    tmp.y <- c(tmp.y, 0, tmp.y[1])

    polygon(tmp.x, tmp.y, col=col)
    text( 0, 2/3, letter, col=txtcol, cex=1, font=2 )
}

myx <- runif(10)
myy <- rnorm(10)
plot(myx,myy, ylim=c( min(myy)-.1, max(myy)+1) )
my.symbols(myx,myy, ms.mappoint, inches=1,
    col=rainbow(10), letter=LETTERS[1:10], symb.plots=TRUE )
```

The overall shape could use some improvement, but that is just a matter of creating a matrix of x and y values to represent the shape.